# Laravel & Markdown Emails - Hide footer for specific Mails

Tags: laravel

I use Markdown system to send my emails, but for specific emails, I want to hide the footer.

Here is my try :

```
@component('mail::message', ['footer' => false])

Hello,

This is my content !

@endcomponent
```

Is it possible to do it ? I published the vendors, and I understand I can hide footer manualy, but how to do it by code ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the blade `@if` syntax

```php
@if($footer)

@component('mail::footer')
    <!-- footer -->
@endcomponent

@endif
```

Comment: This is what we have in default layout in Laravel : `{{ $footer ?? '' }}`, so it's already like this. But it doesn't work when I call it from email

Comment: You need to adjust the if condition based on your requirements. try with `@if(false)` and you will not have the footer in any mail

Comment: Where do I place this code so ? Sorry I think it doesn't work like you are thinking

Comment: In `resources/views/vendor/mail/html/message.blade.php`